# function pointer declarations in c

Tags: c

I was going through k&r complicated declarations part.I got doubt about this particular declaration.

```
char(*(*x[3])())[5]
```

Why cant it be
`char[5] (*(*x[3])())` 
 And can this declaration be legal?

```
 int* (*(*x)())[2];
```

Comment: See e.g. [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: It is bad syntax, since `[]` must come after the name.

Comment: The syntax of C declarations was (perhaps unwisely) defined to imitate use. You're declaring an array of function pointers, and the functions return array pointers. To call the first function in the array, and get the first `char`  value from what it returns, you could write `(*(*x[0])())[0]`, and that's why the `[]` goes afterwards in the declaration too.

Comment: Please note that there is limited practical use of obscure declarations like these. In any program from the real world, typedefs would have been used instead.

Comment: yes.but its just for learning purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the precedence of operators and applying the spiral rule,

```
char(*(*x[3])())[5]
```

is equivalent to

> x is array of  pointers to  functions returning  pointer to  array of
>   char

But in,

```
char[5] (*(*x[3])())
```

the array subscript should be at the end of the declaration, thus resulting in a syntax error. You'll bump into `nothing` when you apply spiral rule to this.

Also,

```
int* (*(*x)())[2];
```

is perfectly legal and its declaration can be stated as

> x is pointer to  function returning  pointer to  array of  pointer to
>   int

Check out the [Java applet](http://www.muquit.com/muquit/software/cdcl/cdcl.html) which can help you decode complicated declarations and also read these [articles](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/9677) of how to form complicated declarations.

@Steve Jessop's comment also seems plausible as to why the `[]` go at the end.